# Why does the following code not change the table?

Tags: list-manipulation, compile, broken-code, table

Consider the following code:

```
comp1 = Compile[{{acccolumns, _Integer, 2}}, Module[{acccols, ncols},
   ncols = Length[acccolumns[[1]]];
   acccols = acccolumns;
   Do[Do[
     Compile`GetElement[acccols, j, i] == RandomInteger[{0, 1}], {i, 
      1, ncols, 1}], {j, 1, Length[acccols], 1}];
   acccols], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]
```

It should take some table `acccolumns`, replace each of its elements with 0 or 1, and then return the changed table. In reality, it does not work: for

```
ncols = 4;
acccolumns1 = Table[1, ncols];
acccolumns = Table[acccolumns1, 10];
```

the evalution

```
comp1[acccolumns]
```

returns `acccolumns`. Could you please tell me where I made a mistake and how to fix it still being inside the compiled code?

Comment: You probably don't want the double equal sign (==), this is for comparison, not for assigning values.

Comment: I'm probably missing the context here, but from what you show it would be easier and faster to just create the random array from scratch rather than replacing each value one by one.

Comment: @banone : if changing the double sign to the single sign, it does not compile the corresponding line.

Comment: @banone : I need to perform some operation `i, j` iteratively if the corresponding element of this `acccols` is 1. The problem is that for some `i` the code previously did not evaluate. So I need it first to be pre-defined.

Comment: ``Compile`GetElement`` is a getter-function, not a setter-function. Since ``Compile`SetElement`` does not exist, you have to use `Part` as in ordinary _Mathematica_ code. Moreover, `Compile` does not allow call by reference, so you cannot modify the input array. (LibraryLink allows this however.)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher : thanks! "Moreover, Compile does not allow call by reference, so you cannot modify the input array." - this is why I added the string `acccols = acccolumns` (where `acccolumns` is the input) and then change `acccols`. "Since CompileSetElement does not exist, you have to use Part as in ordinary Mathematica code. " - does it mean that if I am restricted to use the construction similar to the above one, I am unavoidably limited by the timing of using `Part`?

Comment: "does it mean that if I am restricted to use the construction similar to the above one, I am unavoidably limited by the timing of using Part?" Yes, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Does this what you want?

```
comp1 = Compile[{{in, _Integer, 2}}, Module[{},
   RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {Length[in], 
     Length[in[[1]]]}]], {{Length[_], _Integer}}, 
  CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]
```

With this:

```
comp1[acccolumns]

{{1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 
  0, 1}}
```

Comment: Thanks! However, the main ingredient is to have some pre-defined table `acccolumns` with an arbitrary content and then to be able to change only some of its columns. So this structure with two cycles seems to be essential.

Comment: You may always change any element or columns after randomization.